# Groovy: Get index of all occurences of sublist from arraylist

Tags: groovy

I am new to groovy and trying to find the indexes of all sublists in a list.
I am trying to use something like Collections.indexOfSubList like in java but it gives exception saying it applies on Lists and not ArrayLists.

So I am trying to define my own function. I am finding all the indices of all the elements in the smaller list existing in the longer list and then subtracting the indices of the result array. If it comes to 1 then I am considering that index to a sublist.

I know that I have the logic a little twisted. Can somebody guide with a better and efficient way of doing this.

Below is my code:

```
    List list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3]
List list2 = [1,2]

index1 = list1.findIndexValues {
    it == list2[0];
}

index2 = list1.findIndexValues {
    it == list2[1];
}
println index1
println index2

result = []
for (int i = 0; i < index1.size(); i++) {
        result.add(index2[i]-index1[i]);
}
println result
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Edit:*** no longer uses `Collections` due to new issue re: Elastic Search.

The following code traverses along the source list, creating a sublist. It checks the sublist to see if it starts with the target list. See the asserts below (e.g. the indexes are 0-based):

```
def listStartsWithSubList = { source, target ->
    def result = false

    if (source.size() >= target.size()) {
        result = true

        target.eachWithIndex { item, index ->
            result = result && (item == source[index])
        }
    }

    result
}

def indexOfSubLists = { source, target ->
    def results = []

    source.eachWithIndex { item, index ->
        def tmpList = source[index..source.size()-1]
        if (listStartsWithSubList(tmpList, target)) {
            results << index
        }
    }

    results
}

assert [1] == indexOfSubLists([1,2,3], [2,3])
assert [2] == indexOfSubLists([1,2,3], [3])
assert [] == indexOfSubLists([1,2,3], [4])
assert [0,6] == indexOfSubLists([1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3], [1,2])
```

Comment: Thanks this help. But I am trying to use this code in groovy script in elasticsearch and it gives me an error saying: Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Collections for class. Do you have an idea about that as well?

Comment: I have updated the code: replaced use of `Collections`. This is also more efficient than the previous version, as the scope of the new code is simpler.

Comment: Thanks, this indeed was faster.